# sqlalchemy count from 2 tables at the same time

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model Case, let's say like this:

```
class Case(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cases"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

A Beer model, like this:

```
class Beer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "beers"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    case_id = db.Column(
        "case_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("cases.id"), nullable=False, index=True
    )
```

And a Soda model, like this:

```
class Soda(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sodas"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    case_id = db.Column(
        "case_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("cases.id"), nullable=False, index=True
    )
```

A Soda or a Beer objects necessarily belong to a Case. So a Case in hierarchically higher than a Soda or a Beer. A Soda and a Beer are not related in anyway. A Soda and a Beer can belong to the same Case.

I would like, for each Case, to get the count of Beers AND Coke.

I tried something like this:

```
all_nbr = session.query(Case, func.count(Beer.id), func.count(Coke.id)).join(Beer, Coke).group_by(Case.id)
```

But it doesn't work (I believe it gives me only the number of Beers).

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use subqueries to solve this

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from decimal import Decimal
from sqlalchemy import func

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base()
session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

class Case(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cases"
    id = sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Beer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "beers"
    id = sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    case_id = sa.Column(
        "case_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("cases.id"), nullable=False, index=True
    )


class Soda(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sodas"
    id = sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    case_id = sa.Column(
        "case_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("cases.id"), nullable=False, index=True
    )

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

engine.echo = True

session.add(Case(id=1))
session.add(Case(id=2))

session.add(Beer(id=1, case_id=1))
session.add(Beer(id=2, case_id=1))
session.add(Beer(id=3, case_id=1))
session.add(Beer(id=4, case_id=2))


session.add(Soda(id=1, case_id=2))
session.add(Soda(id=2, case_id=2))
session.add(Soda(id=3, case_id=2))
session.add(Soda(id=4, case_id=1))

session.commit()

beer_count = (session.query(
                Case.id, 
                func.count(Beer.id).label("total_beers")
            ).
            outerjoin(Beer, Beer.case_id == Case.id).
            group_by(Beer.case_id)
            ).subquery()

soda_count = (session.query(
                Case.id, 
                func.count(Soda.id).label("total_sodas")
            ).
            outerjoin(Soda, Soda.case_id == Case.id).
            group_by(Soda.case_id)
            ).subquery()

cases = (session.query(
            Case, 
            beer_count.c.total_beers,
            soda_count.c.total_sodas,
        ).
        outerjoin(beer_count, beer_count.c.id == Case.id)
        .outerjoin(soda_count, soda_count.c.id == Case.id)
        .group_by(Case)
        )
```

This will give you count of beers and soda per case